# Asynch class in Wildfly

Tags: jboss, wildfly

in JBOSS versions prior to Wildfly there is the class

```
org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.Asynch
```

which one can use the make asynchronous call.
I can't find this class anywhere in Wildfly. I'm not intending to use the

```
@Asynchronous
```

annotation. This is the error that I get:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.Asynch

The class actually come from the `jboss-ejb3.jar` which is not available on Wildfly

Thanks in avance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import it directly from the javax.ejb.* package. This is the standard EE7 location and works on Wildly 8, 9 and 10. You neglected to tell us which version of Wildfly you were using.

```
import javax.ejb.Asynchronous;
```